# Add a column that is the sum of multiple other columns

Tags: sql

I have a query below which contains several SUM(CASE WHEN statements which is providing me with the data I need however now I am stuck as I need a final column which sums all the values from each column and what I have attempted so far has not yielded any results.

NB: Dates come from the database i am working from as an INT data type so they have been converted as shown.  Data type cannot be updated.

Desired Result: Populate Sum of all values in column X

| CUSTOMER | CUSTOMER_NAME | CURRENCY | CURRENT | 1-30 DAYS | 31-60 DAYS | 61-90 DAYS | 91-120 DAYS | +120 DAYS | X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000184 | SARL DIGI | EUR | 0.00 | 12894.00 | 356.00 | 4042.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |  |

Below is my code so far.

```
SELECT
FS.CUNO CUSTOMER,
OC.CUNM CUSTOMER_NAME,
FS.CUCD CURRENCY,
SUM(
CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), FS.DUDT), 112) BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-1, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, -0 , GETDATE()) THEN FS.CUAM ELSE 0 END) 
    AS [CURRENT],

SUM(
CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), FS.DUDT), 112)BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-30, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) THEN FS.CUAM ELSE 0 END) 
    AS [1-30 DAYS],

SUM(
CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), FS.DUDT), 112)BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-60, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, -31, GETDATE()) THEN FS.CUAM ELSE 0 END) 
    AS [31-60 DAYS],

SUM(
CASE
    WHEN CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), FS.DUDT), 112)BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-90, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, -61, GETDATE()) THEN FS.CUAM ELSE 0 END) 
    AS [61-90 DAYS],

SUM(
CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), FS.DUDT), 112)BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-120, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, -91, GETDATE()) THEN FS.CUAM ELSE 0 END)
    AS [91-120 DAYS],

SUM(
CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), FS.DUDT), 112)BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-999, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, - 121, GETDATE()) THEN FS.CUAM ELSE 0 END) 
    AS [+120 DAYS]

FROM FSLEDG FS
LEFT JOIN OCUSMA OC ON OC.CUNO = FS.CUNO
WHERE FS.YEA4 = '2021'
GROUP BY FS.CUNO, OC.CUNM, FS.CUCD
HAVING MIN(FS.TRCD) = 10 AND MAX(FS.TRCD) = 10
ORDER BY FS.CUNO
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add the following conditional sum to your select:

```sql
SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), FS.DUDT), 112) BETWEEN
              DATEADD(DAY, -999, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
         THEN FS.CUAM ELSE 0 END) AS [TOTAL]
```

This simply uses a date range which covers all the previous conditional sums in your query.

Comment: this worked and i understand the logic.  Appreciate your support.